# What are the conditions for react to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure when react re-renders. I don't have any performance issues, nor am I trying to optimize performance right now.
I am just curios on when react does re-render.

As far as I can understand, react will draw everything before running useEffect, and after useEffect has run it will draw again.
Meaning that it should call the return of NewLobby once, then useEffect once, and then NewLobby once, resulting in a log of :

```js
hello
rerun
hello
```

That should also be true for when I hit the refresh button.

The actual behaviour is different though => The first time the page loads the console prints :

```js
hello
hello
hello
rerun
hello
```

The refresh button works as expected. Why are there 2 more repaints?

### My Component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BACKEND_URL } from 'GConfig';

const NewLobby = () => {
  const initialStateFactory = () => {
    return {
      loading: false,
      error: false,
      lobbies: 'Loading ...',
    };
  };

  const [lobbies, setLobbies] = useState(initialStateFactory());
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const fetchLobbies = async () => {
        const result = await (
          await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/play/lobbies`, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
          })
        ).json();
        return result;
      };
      const lobbies = await fetchLobbies();
      console.log('rerun');
      setLobbies(s => {
        return { ...s, lobbies };
      });
    })();
  }, [refresh]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{console.log('hello')}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setRefresh(s => s + 1)}>Refresh</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default NewLobby;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally recommend using [Why did you render?](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render) for these kinds of issues. Give it a spin, it's almost guarenteed to point out your issue.